# cocos2d-x 3.8 - Use network extension

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to use HttpClient in my Cocos2d-x project. I'm using cocos2d-x 3.8 and developing with Xcode.

Some things I tried to do:

- I was looking cocos-ext.h file and I saw network was removed. In this thread explains that it was moved to core: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/why-remove-network-on-cocos2d-x-3-0-beta/10804
- I saw in network/HttpAsynConnection-apple.h there are two namespaces declared, cocos2d and network
- When I add this to my code the compiler says: no member named 'network' in namespace 'cocos2d'

  cocos2d::network::HttpRequest* request = new cocos2d::network::HttpRequest();

Probably I'm missing something? I need to add any preprocessor macro to enable network? Some param in c++ compiler to enable sub-namespaces?

I read all documentation here, in cocos2d-x.org and Stackoverflow with no success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but I completely forgot including HttpRequest header file. This is what I missed:

```
#include "network/HttpClient.h"
```